# TFS 2010 build compiling TypeScript version 0.9.1.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, typescript

I'm hoping to stop including the generated JavaScript files in TFS source control, but I haven't managed to get the compiler to run on a build.

I've followed [this chap's example](http://daysincode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/typescript-msbuild-as-part-of-project.html) and edited the project file to give me:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Before Build" Importance="high" />
    <CallTarget Targets="TypeScriptBuild"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="TypeScriptBuild"  Inputs="@(TypeScriptCompile)" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy" Condition="'$(CompileTypeScript)'=='true'">
    <Message Text="Building typescript file - @(TypeScriptCompile)"  Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\tsc&quot; -target ES3 &quot;@(TypeScriptCompile)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

I've changed the file location where the tsc executable is and removed the TypeScript version information, but it isn't doing anything for me. I'm a complete newbie at this build stuff so would appreciate any help, or tips on how to debug it.

**Edit 1**
Removed

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
```

as it was redundant - this is added individually for every TypeScript file in the project.

The only warnings I'm getting are about inconclusive unit tests. I assumed that `<Message Text="Before Build" Importance="high" />` would produce some kind of log message but I can't see it anywhere.

**Edit 2**
Got it working *locally within Visual Studio* by putting

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="Compiling typescript...">
  </Message>
<Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; -target ES3 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
```

at the end of the .csproj file. For some reason this doesn't work when TFS is building it. If I change the TypeScript compiler file location to something nonsensical it complains, but when it's correct there are no JavaScript files produced.

Comment: This is what I use for my build / dev https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts

Comment: Do you get any build messages or warnings that might give as a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't have to do any of this.  Make sure this line is in your csproj, before the `</project>`

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

Then install TypeScript on the build machine.  Also you need to make sure the `Build Action` of the `.ts` files is set to `TypeScriptCompile`.  At this point, TypeScript will compile your .ts files and generate the js files.  You won't (and shouldn't) check the .js files into your code repository.

### Unit Tests

You really want your unit tests building with the rest of your code.  Even more, you can run these unit tests at build time and use them to fail the build if any of those tests fail!

Check out [this post on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx?CommentPosted=true) and [this post on codeplex](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/discussions/400818) to help get you started.  It will involve using [Chutzpah](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/).  Also, be aware that the way your .js bundling / delivery may be different when using Chutzpah, since Chutzpah will have to build that bundle for you and I'm not sure how your actual site is doing it.

Comment: You're right, my additional TypeScript-specific sections were not far enough down in the project file :/ 
I still needed an extra section to include the generated JavaScript, as the files are copied to an output directory -
`<Target Name="AddGeneratedJavascript" AfterTargets="CompileTypeScript">
    <Message Text="Adding typescript generated javascript...">
    </Message>
    <Message Text="@(GeneratedJavascript ->'%(Identity)')">
    </Message>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="@(GeneratedJavascript ->'%(Identity)')">
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>`

Comment: Hrm, you shouldn't have to, though it may depend on if your .js files are actually referenced to, from your csproj.  I know when I package an azure webrole, it wont pick up the .js files unless they are setup as `dependentupon` the .ts files.  So that's how we have it, included in the csproj but not checked into TFS.

Comment: We don't have any references to the JavaScript files. If I publish the project from Visual Studio then it works as is due to the TypeScript targets, but I need my extra target for the TFS build.

Comment: Weird.  It should automatically build without adding the extra target.  Did you install typescript on the TFS build machine?

Comment: Yes it all builds correctly, the problem is we have an extra build step where the output is copied to another directory. It doesn't know to copy the generated files, which is why they need to be included as content as a custom target.

Comment: Oh, are you doing some sort of non standard deployment technique?  Like something other than web deploy?